# Como puedo acceder a un hidden value usando python

Tags: html, python, web-scrapping

necesito **acceder** al **contenido** de una cabecera de tipo `type="hidden"` pero cuando realizo el **parse a html** (probe tambien con lxml y fue lo mismo) este no reconoce la etiqueta `value` como parte del **html** el html orignal pone esto
`<input id="url" type="hidden" name="url" value="EdevaqOMG4g9d9IALluXJHzkYRlUJr4KnidLanOwb7g6KNPrFMzvESI5kXp4Q64SY0snzYIg3ftqhuGt4To8w0SX2HLnAR+J1DaZx6aGw68=">` pero cuando realizo el **parse** y filtro con beutifullsoup la etiqueta `value` lo q obtengo es `<input id="url" name="url" type="hidden"/>` este es mi codigo:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://ejemplo.com'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
codex = soup.find('input')
print(codex)
```

Comment: Te pueden estar ocurriendo dos cosas: que no estés seleccionando el input correcto o que el valor de ese input se esté modificando dinámicamente via javascript. Cuando ves el código fuente (el fuente, no desde el inspector) de la web el valor está definido?

Por otro lado: el value lo estás recuperando con `.value` o con `.get('value')`?

Comment: Probé pero el problema radica en q debido a la propiedad `type="hidden"` de la etiqueta provoca q el BeautifulSoup ignore el value de esta etiqueta como si no existiese en código pues probé imprimir todo el html y no aparece en él, si embargo desde el inspector si lo puedo ver aunque no me permite interactuar con el, sin embargo cuando elimino manualmente la propiedad hidden me permite acceder sin problemas al value.

Comment: Entonces el problema es el que te mencionaba antes. No tiene que ver con que el type sea hidden. Simplemente el valor está siendo modificado con JavaScript en el navegador cliente. Para poder hacer lo que quieres tendrás que utilizar alguna solución tipo selenium, si utilizas requests sólo vas a obtener el html sin que se ejecute el código js